# Grant Permission in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hortonworks-data-platform, metastore

I'm trying to set Grant Permissions on Hive 14.0 using Hortonworks Sandbox HDP2.2 as one-node-system. This questions goes similar to unanswered question from march: [grant permissions in hive does not work on hdp2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29206980/grant-permissions-in-hive-does-not-work-on-hdp2-2).

I followed the configuration steps of the [a Hive-Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/SQL+Standard+Based+Hive+Authorization).

After log into hive shell (ssh with root) I tried:

```
CREATE ROLE testing;
```

> FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Failed to retrieve roles for root: Metastore Authorization api invocation for remote metastore is disabled in this configuration.

If I try the same with another user with hue / beeswax the query finished. If I do

```
SHOW ROLES;
```

I got this error, without any log details:

> Expected state FINISHED, but found ERROR

My Settings are these (made tags with blanc to show them here)

- **hive-site.xml** (those which are listed in the hive-wiki-link)

  ```
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.users.in.admin.role</name>
    <value>hue,hive</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.security.metastore.authorization.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.StorageBasedAuthorizationProvider,org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.MetaStoreAuthzAPIAuthorizerEmbedOnly</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdConfOnlyAuthorizerFactory</value>
  </property>
  ```
- **hiveserver2-site.xml** (all settings)

  ```
  <property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.enabled</name>
      <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hive.security.authorization.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.authorization.plugin.sqlstd.SQLStdHiveAuthorizerFactory</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hive.security.authenticator.manager</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.security.SessionStateUserAuthenticator</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
      <value>''</value>
  </property>
  <property>
      <name>hive.conf.restricted.list</name>
      <value>hive.security.authorization.enabled,hive.security.authorization.manager,hive.security.authenticator.manager</value>
  </property>
  ```

Hope anyone has an idea.

[Edit]The settings in *hive-site.xml* were already set - I made there no changes.

[Edit2]After change settings I did *hiveserver2 restart* and performed a reboot of the sandbox.

[Edit3]Error message comes to every user, not only for root (u can see it at error message). If I try users with admin role (hive-site.xml) like "hive", I got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to make it runable - [thanks to *Thejas Nair* of Hortonworks](http://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/grant-permissions-not-working/).

Here are the points:

- You should change all setting with Ambari.
- Don't change *hive.metastore.uris*-setting
- Manually change *hiveserver2-site.xml* property of *hive.security.authorization.manager*
- Copy *hiveserver2-site.xml* to */etc/hive/conf.server/*
- Restart hiveserver2
- Use only beeline for SQL permissions